# Issues with writing scope for expired & closed cases - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

- i am trying to write a scope for the model Event
- i want to display all events that have expired and have been closed

schema

```
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.date     "date"
    t.boolean  "close"
  end
```

event.rb

```
scope :expired_or_closed_events, -> {where(['close = ? OR close IS ?', true] || ['date < ?', Date.current])}
```

i tried the above scope but i get the below error

```
2.3.0 :014 >   events.expired_or_closed_events
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: close = ? OR close IS ?
```

> could one kindly advise me how i write the scope for this correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scope should be:

```
scope :expired_or_closed, -> { where("close = true OR date < ?", DateTime.now) }
```

Or using Arel

```
scope :expired_or_closed, -> { where(arel_table[:close].eq(true).or(arel_table[:date].lt(DateTime.now)) }
```

Note that I use `expired_or_closed` not `expired_or_closed_events`, because we are defining this scope in Event model, using `events' is redundant.

Comment: Nice approach for naming

Answer (score 3):

**Use This**

```
scope :expired_or_closed_events, -> {  where( "close == ?  || date < ? ", true, Date.current ) }



I think your condition should be **close == ? **


 otherwise no sense of condition, which always calculate as true
```

Comment: According Hieu name should be expired_or_closed